# Spark Scala equivalent for SKEW join hints

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark SQL has a skew hint available (please see [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/skew-join.html#relation-columns-and-skew-values)). Is there an equivalent hint available for Spark Scala?

**Example**
This is the Spark SQL code where fact table has skewed ProductId column:

```
SELECT /*+ SKEW('viewFact', 'ProductId') */
    RevSumDivisionName, RevSumCategoryName, CloudAddOnFlag,
    SUM(ActualRevenueAmt) AS RevenueUSD, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM viewFact
INNER JOIN viewPMST ON viewFact.ProductId = viewPMST.ProductId
INNER JOIN viewRsDf ON viewPMST.ProductFamilyId = viewRsDf.ProductFamilyId
INNER JOIN viewRevH ON viewRsDf.RevSumCategoryId = viewRevH.RevSumCategoryId
GROUP BY RevSumDivisionName, RevSumCategoryName, CloudAddOnFlag
```

Same join in Scala:

```
inFact
   .join(inPMst, Seq("ProductId"))
   .join(inRsDf, Seq("ProductFamilyId"))
   .join(inRevH, Seq("RevSumCategoryId"))
.groupBy($"RevSumDivisionName", $"RevSumCategoryName", $"CloudAddOnFlag")
.agg(sum($"ActualRevenueAmt") as "RevenueUSD", count($"*") as "Cnt")
```

I'm just unable finding syntax for the skew hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Spark SQL has a skew hint available

It does not. Databricks platform has, but it is a proprietary extension (same as indexing) not available in Spark as such.

> I'm just unable finding syntax for the skew hint.

In general case query plan hints are passed using `hint` method which can be used like this

```
val hint: String = ???
inFact.join(inPMst.hint(hint),  Seq("ProductId")))
```

Comment: thank you for recommendation and correcting my assumption; `val hint: String = "SKEW('viewFact', 'ProductId')"` does the trick; please do you want to add it to your answer and claim the solution?

Comment: are there any examples on how hints can be used (outside the databricks platform)?