# Does Spark support skew hints?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm facing some data skew issues, and I wanted to see if Spark hints could help me. However, I'm not sure if skew hints are supported. These sites:  https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/skew-join.html#relation-columns-and-skew-values [Spark Scala equivalent for SKEW join hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880616/spark-scala-equivalent-for-skew-join-hints) both imply that yes, they are supported.

However, https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hint-framework.html#spark-analyzer claims that `Spark SQL supports COALESCE and REPARTITION and BROADCAST hints. All remaining unresolved hints are silently removed from a query plan at analysis.`, which would imply that my skew hint would also be ignored.

Which one is correct? I am running Spark 2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** As of Spark 2.4 Apache Spark doesn't support skew hints.

You confuse two things:

- [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) which is open source project maintained by the [Apache Software Foundation](https://www.apache.org/)
- Databricks Unified Analytics platform which is a proprietary product build on top of Apache Spark.

The former one supports a set of features that are not present in the Apache Spark, and sometimes even diverge in the execution model. You shouldn't judge Apache Spark features looking at the Databricks documentation. Skewed joins are one of these features (among mutable storage, indexing and other tools).

Note that there other proprietary platforms built on top of Spark, which might provide its own extensions and modify Spark's behavior so you shouldn't use their documentation.